# How to create envelopes using cURL. I am tried below code but showing null

Tags: docusignapi

I try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issue

I try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issueI try to create envelopes. The above code is not working. Please review the code and tell me the issue

```
<?php
$realpath = "uploads/";
$doc_file = 'dummy.pdf';
$content_bytes = file_get_contents($realpath . $doc_file);
$base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);

$certificate_location = 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.26\extras\ssl\cacert.pem';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $certificate_location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $certificate_location);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://demo.docusign.net/v2.1/accounts/2c5281fc-8adb-4bb1-a764-0a77bd98ec0e/envelopes');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"documents\": [\n    {\n      \"documentBase64\": $base64_file_content,\n      \"documentId\": 15464655,\n      \"fileExtension\": \"pdf\",\n      \"name\": \"document12345\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"emailSubject\": \"Simple Signing Example\",\n  \"recipients\": {\n    \"signers\": [\n      {\n        \"email\": \"sandeep0822@gmail.com\",\n        \"name\": \"Sandeep\",\n        \"recipientId\": \"{{recipientId}}\"\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  \"status\": \"sent\"\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAUABwCAxDrMAUfbSAgAgARe2kRH20gCAPvG8RYXzvVIl65odwsvffsVAAEAAAAYAAgAAAAxAAAAMgAAACsAAAA4AAAALQAAAC8AAAA1AAAAMwAAAA0AJAAAAGFhOWZhNjgzLWY0YjQtNGE3Mi05NWE3LTNiNDM0NjczYTVhMyIAJAAAAGFhOWZhNjgzLWY0YjQtNGE3Mi05NWE3LTNiNDM0NjczYTVhMzAAgEXPZP5G20g3ANtSvxlqLSpBqqxieM2bkLM.PyRvZdPTQTrVD5aSKZ0hrRmB9x3ZQ6CeCz5GwcEGLe60qN4XOeE7NT8a83NnHldTIcXBJIosI2WiohFz1L8uyth6Ea38Vk4oAni0gnTXHUKSRyERa7R-gEDNoNdIHpdth7iMQXLMDUPcCY03o0xQV3AP3Oov1Pk770rTBi5XRkrsqpKqLd1HqlrKPF6ahhxai00R1-d0q0ITrwIHzXNdGdd5s7PWpuhYNQUgdHpb5rwqPE51PX48KBBB2g-xGa16ngqUC7EchgtbtGkZBzHKNmiGQ9kufWLi74WlLFgidxh1jxaBOZsm1MT723PbV-1ABOtecZYuU9Eurqp1K5PxLQ';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo '</pre>';
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: please don't' share your access code publicly, as it allows anyone out there to make API calls with your account

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got the access token that you have in here (please don't share it publicly) but this token is only good for 8 hours and only for the account/user that you used to obtain it (can't use someone else's etc.)

This means that you have to have a way to obtain it in your code, you cannot hardcode it and expect your code to work.

You can use JWT and then use the PHP package (SDK) that has a method to obtain an access token to make it easier for you, or you can use Auth Code Grant and have the user login to DocuSign on your PHP website.